# Why can't I view my home page like I can on a local host

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, digital-ocean

I am trying to upload my website on digital ocean using express, node and react. I can view my website on localhost:3000 but when I run nodemon on the publicip:3000 all I see is /root/website/src/index.html displayed on the page. Here is the server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//Set port
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;


//Import path
const path = require('path');

//Static files
app.use(express.static('build'));

//Server will use index.html
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.send(path.join(__dirname + '/src/index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port ${PORT}');
});
```

Comment: use `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/index.html'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using res.send() then it will send the path of the file. And path.join should contain the values separated with commas as it takes the values as string array.

Try this

If you want the actual file to send.

`res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname ,"src/index.html"));`